# Check whether TempDB was ever out of space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. Is there any DMV to verify whether TempDB was `ever` out of space? I am looking for a query that will provide the times on which tempdb was full.

Note: I already know that following query will provide `current` details.

```
USE tempdb
exec sp_spaceused
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [Troubleshooting Insufficient Disk Space in tempdb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the error logs for a message saying that tempdb tried to grow but couldn't.

The message should look soemthing like:

> "Could not allocate space for object ... in
>   database ... because the ... filegroup is full. Create
>   disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the
>   filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting
>   autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup. "

Comment: Yes, Management -> SQL Server Error Logs

Comment: Yes it is the Logs made under Manegement of SQL Server!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error logs which will specify you that the temdb is full and you need to increase the space or better manage the space and also check [Troubleshooting Insufficient Disk Space in tempdb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Server Activity History Report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280683%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

There's a section in the report devoted to `tempdb` in the Sql Server Activity Graph in the report. That might show the history of the disk space etc for `tempdb` in the past.

```
Different aspects of SQL Server activity can be accessed from the SQL Server Activity graph. The reports that you can obtain by clicking a point on the SQL Compilations/sec graph line are as follows:
Connections and sessions
Requests
Plan cache hit ratio
tempdb characteristics
```